# How can I filter AJAX requests from console in Firebug?

Tags: javascript, ajax, firebug

I'm trying to debug an app, which is very heavy on ajax requests (at least one per second). Firebug displays each of those requests in its console, which makes it very difficult to see my own console.log prints. Is it possible to temporarily filter ajax requests from appearing in the console?

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but here are some really useful tips for better console management - http://labs.blitzagency.com/?p=2101

Comment: one per second...I hate to see your bandwidth bill

Comment: why don't you turn off or reduce the frequency of the undesirable ajax requests while debugging?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a small arrow on the console tab, you can turn off what it displays there.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On the console tab, click the down arrow. In the options, uncheck the Show XMLHttpRequets option.